# Electric fields affecting recombination of virtual particle pairs

Tags: electric-fields, vacuum, polarization

Besides the Schwinger effect, whereby a strong enough electric field can cause the creation of virtual particle pairs in the quantum vacuum, I have also read that a suitable electric field is able to interfere with the recombination of such particle pairs thereby causing a 'real' electron charge to persist.

Does anyone know if this effect has a name and if there are any papers or centers of research into it? Thanks

Comment: [Vacuum polarisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization)?

Comment: My question refers to the process whereby an electric field prevents recombination after polarisation and not the process of vacuum polarisation itself